# TypeLite - add KnockoutObservable to certain properties

Tags: typescript, typelite

Let's say I have a server-side POCO class as follows:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumPages { get; set; }
}
```

TypeLite will convert it as follows:

```
interface Book {
    Isbn: string;
    Title: string;
    NumPages: string;
}
```

What I'd like to do is be able to decorate the NumPages attribute server-side so that it's like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [TsObservable]  // doesn't need to be called this - an attribute seems like a nice way to do it though
    public int NumPages { get; set; }
}
```

...and the client side version would then automatically make alterations to the interface as follows.

```
interface Book {
    Isbn: string;
    Title: string;
    NumPages: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}
```

Is this something which can be achieved with TypeLite? Ideally I'd like to be able to selectively make each property within a class Observable, but at a push, I guess all properties in the class could be observable.

I just can't seem to work out how to modify the .tt file to make it happen.

Comment: You can do this using Typewriter. Not sure about TypeLite

Comment: Thanks - I already looked at TypeWriter before writing this question, but that brings some different issues to the party.

Comment: indeed it does, it works within Visual Studio primarily. That said, I find it pretty easy to work with and the reflective model is deep